# Can capital loss be applied for tax for non-consecutive years?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-loss

If I have realized a large amount of capital loss this year, can I choose  which of the following years that the capital loss can apply to offset taxable income, and how much capital loss is applied in the years I choose? For example, can I apply a loss of $1000 for the 3rd year, a loss of $4000 for the 5th year, and don't apply  any loss for this year, next year, the 4th year?

For example, suppose this year, my income is very low and negligible, and therefore my tax for this year is going to be zero. Can I choose not to apply capital loss for tax for this year? But save them for some years in the future, when I have much more income and therefore nonzero tax to pay?

Comment: how about getting a tax adviser?

Comment: @littleadv: I wonder how to get a tax adviser and whether I have to pay for that?

Comment: you open your local yellow-pages and look for Enrolled Agents or CPA's or Tax Attorneys. Then you call them up and ask for a consultation. Most provide initial consultation for free, for continuous question asking you would probably have to pay some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capital loss can only be applied to offset capital gain (Correction: As JoeTaxpayer rightly mentioned, $3K of the capital losses can offset ordinary income in any year, after offsetting all the capital gains). Remembering your other questions, IRA distributions totaling to less than the basis **do not** create capital loss.

You can carry forward the capital loss until you've exhausted it, but it is being recalculated each year anew. You cannot have capital loss in year X, capital gain in the year X+1, and then offset the capital gain in the year X+2 with the losses carried forward from the year X. You must offset the gains of the year X+1, and if you still have losses remained, you carry them forward.

If you don't have capital gains - there's nothing to apply the losses carried forward to, and you carry them forward as they are to the next year, and so on, until capital gains appear to offset them.

Comment: Thanks! "You cannot have capital loss in year X, capital gain in the year X+1, and then offset the capital gain in the year X+2 with the losses carried forward from the year X. You must offset the gains of the year X+1." Does it mean that even when the tax for the year X+1 is zero because of low income only, must the loss in year X still be used to offset positive capital gain in year X+1, even though the loss doesn't help to reduce any tax?

Comment: @Tim did I mention the tax liability anywhere? I didn't. What made you think it has any bearing? Its irrelevant.

Comment: So you mean that if there is positive capital gain in year X+1, the left-over capital loss in year X must be used to offset the gain in year X+1, no matter the loss help to reduce the tax or not (for example, the tax is already zero because the income is too low)?

Comment: @Tim, I mean that if you have a capital gain, and you have a carry-forward capital loss from a prior year - you **must** use it, or lose it. What happens to your tax liability is irrelevant. You don't have to apply it, if you don't want to, but you won't be able to carry it further forward without applying it.

Comment: @littleadv - losses first apply to gains, but then $3000 per year can be used to offset ordinary income. The rest of your answer is correct.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer you're right, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Thanks! As littleadv said, whenever there is capital gain, capital loss must be used to offset it, otherwise the entire capital loss will expire. I wonder if $3000 loss per year that can be used to offset ordinary income after offsetting capital gain is optional or required? I hope to save the loss for some future years when I have more ordinary income such that my tax is non-zero, whereas my current ordinary income is too low and my tax is zero.

Comment: Required. But it doesn't get "used" if your taxable income is zero. Yes, it will be used on 10% income, the first bracket.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Thanks! By "Required. But it doesn't get 'used' if your taxable income is zero", do you mean applying capital loss is a must although a waste, or no waste here, i.e. will leftover loss be reduced? I notice that capital gain and loss are reported on schedule D, and considered before calculating taxable income in Form 1040.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Thanks! In Form 1040, the capital loss is applied on line 13 with Schedule D, which is before adjustment, deduction and exemption can apply. So even when the wage is so low that it would be completely offset by adjustment, deduction or exemption if there were no capital loss, the capital loss still has to be applied first before adjustment, deduction or exemption, which leave no chance to save the loss for future years?

Comment: @Tim that is correct.

Comment: I am not correct in one of my comments above. Income of the exact std deduction amount ($5800 in 2011) will not affect carrry-forward loss. But, if income is offset by your exemption ($3700 in '11) the $3000 can be partially or fully lost. I produced a test return on TurboTax. A $5800 gross income shows whatever loss was carried from '10 passing through, the worksheet adding it back in, even though prior calculations "try" to use it up.